# 「公然站到占世界五分之一人口的中国人民的对立面」里的「站到占」是什么意思？

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

我今天看的文章讨论美国最新泄露的消息和中方发言人华春莹的反应。据报道，美国政府正在考虑禁止共产党员和家人入境美国。不过下面的「站到占」我完全不了解。

> 华春莹称，现在美国官方还没有人出来澄清这是不是fake news（假新闻），但是如果这个报道属实，那么美方无疑是公然地选择与十四亿中国人民作对，公然**站到占**世界五分之一人口的中国人民的对立面。这是完全违背中美两国人民的意愿和二十一世纪的潮流的。
> <sub>[美要限制中共党员旅美？中方：如属实，是与十四亿中国人作对](https://www.sohu.com/a/408198006_260616),2020年07月17</sub>

据我了解，华春莹还不确定泄露的消息是不是准确，不过准确的话，她认为美国公然反对中国人。

**问题**：在上面的片段中「站到占」是什么意思？

Comment: Parsing issue - 站到占 is not a phrase. Hint: break it into 公然站到 X 的对立面, X can be something else, and in this case it is 占世界五分之一人口的中国人民.

Comment: FWIW, "占世界五分之一人口的中国人民" doesn't look quite right. 占世界五分之一人口的中国 is an improvement.

Comment: The phrase '与十四亿中国人作对' said it best.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *问题：在上面的片段中「站到占」是什么意思？*

不是 「站到占」而是 「站到 占世界五分之一人口的 ....」

> [公然] [站到] [**占**世界五分之一人口的] [中国人民的] [对立面]

> 「公然站到 **占**世界五分之一人口的 中国人民的 对立面」

> "Openly stand on the opposite side of the Chinese people, which **account for** one-fifth of the world's population"

Answer (score 2):

- 站到__的對立面 means literally "to stand on the opposite side of __ ", which should be interpreted here as "to be opposed to __".
- 占 here signifies "to possess".

Combining up, the clause can be translated as "to be opposed to China which possesses one-fifth of the world's population".

Answer (score 0):

- 主语: 美方
- 谓语: 公然站到   (公然: 副词, 到: 副词, 都是修饰 站 这个谓语)
- 宾语: 对立面  ( [占世界五分之一人口的] 形容词, 修饰 中国人民,  [中国人民的]形容词, 修饰 对立面   )

so the simplified sentence is : 美方 站到 对立面.